# Issue on returning Values from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-5.0

I have a C# method on ASP.Net which populating Data to a List as:

```
public ICollection<Book> SelectFilteredBooks(){
 using (APPEntities entities = new APPEntities()) {
   try{
   FilterItemList list = (FilterItemList)HttpContext.Current.Session["FilterList"];
          if (list != null)
             {
               Dictionary<String, Object> parameters = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
               String whereParam = FilterItemList.WhereParameter(list.ItemList, "it", ItemType.Book, parameters);
                  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereParam))
                      {
                         var allResults = entities.BookS.Where(whereParam);
                         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> kvp in parameters)
                          {
                   allResults.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));                                 }

                     return allResults.ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => new Need { TITLE = d.TITLE.ToLower() });
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                      Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                 }
                 return entities.BookS.ToList();
             }
         }
```

Now my problem is on `allResults.ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => new Need { TITLE = d.TITLE.ToLower() });` which is ONLY returning the TITLE column values. can you please let me know if there is a other point which I can convert the value to Lower? Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting allResults.ToList<Book>().ConvertAll(d => new Need { TITLE = d.TITLE.ToLower() }); would do?

Comment: I just want to make all values in TITLE to be Lower

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write something like:

```
 var list = allResults.ToList<Book>()
 list.ForEach(d => d.TITLE = d.TITLE.ToLower());
 return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert in a different place:

```
allResults.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString().ToLower()));
```

Comment: Hi TheGreekYouNeed I updated the code but I am getting this compiler error now"'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToLower' and no extension method 'ToLower' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"